Probability that Brownian Motion takes value in an $L^2$-Ball
Suppose $W:[0,1]\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a standard Brownian motion on the unit interval. With $L^2[0,1]$ denoting the space of real-valued square-integrable functions with standard norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, consider the probability space $(L^2[0,1], \mathcal{B}(L^2[0,1]), P)$ defined by $P(B)= P(W \in B)$; i.e. $P(B)$ is the probability that a standard Brownian motion lies in the set $B$.
Is it true that for any (open) ball $$B_v(\delta) = \{ f \in L^2[0,1] : \; \| f -v \|_2 < \delta \}$$
we always have that $P(B_v(\delta))>0$?

Basically you need to determine probability that $Y_t = \int_{0}^{1}B_t^2 , dt < \delta^2$. I'm pretty sure $Y_t$ is well studied by now.

The answer is positive. Indeed, there exists a continuous function $g\in B_v(\delta)$. Moreover, for some $r>0$, $$B^\infty_g(r) := \{h \in C([0,1]): ||h-g||_\infty<r\}\subset B_v(\delta).$$ It is well known that the distribution of $W$ on $C([0,1])$ has full support, so $P(B^\infty_g(r))>0$, hence, $P(B_v(\delta))>0$.

This is awesome @zhoraster thank you! This is not the first time you have come to my rescue. I thought about asking the question using C[0,1] balls instead since I could see that that would imply the $L^2$ case. Do you know of a reference where it is shown that $P(B_g^\infty(r))>0$ for all $g,r$?

NVM @zhoraster! Found this proof on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064700/sample-path-of-brownian-motion-within-epsilon-distance-of-continuous-function
