Universality of Brownian Motion in continuous functions
it is a well known fact about Brownian motion $W \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ that if we take any function $f \in C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ then
$$
p:= P(\|W-f\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon) > 0.
$$
In other words for any fixed continuous function $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ there is positive probability that Brownian motion approximates this function uniformly up to $\varepsilon$-distance.
Question: I want to use this fact to show a "universality" property of Brownian motion, in the sense that we can find time shifts of a given Brownian motion $W \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that the above probability is not even positive but one. In this sense Brownian motion is universal since we can approximate every continuous function on $[0,1]$ by a time shift of $B$ arbitrary well.
Statement: Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let $W$ be a Brownian motion on $[0,\infty)$ then
$$
P(\exists T \in \mathbb R \colon \|W_{T+\cdot}-f\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])} < \epsilon ) = 1.
$$
Proof: Consider a sequence of consecutive stopping times $(\tau_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where for each $n \in \mathbb N$ one has $\tau_n =\inf\{t > \tau_{n-1} \colon W_{t} = f(0)\}$ and $\tau_0 = \inf\{t \geq 0 \colon W_t = f(0)\}$, these are the $n$-th time the Brownian motion hits the level of $f(0)$. Observe that since
$$
\limsup_{t \to \infty} W_t = + \infty \quad \text{ and } \quad \liminf_{t \to \infty} W_t = - \infty,
$$
all stopping times are $P$-almost surely finite. The idea is that the progression of $(\tau_n)$ follows of geometric random variable with sucess probability $p$. More precisely,
$$
P(\exists T \in \mathbb R \colon \|W_{T+\cdot} - f\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])} < \epsilon) \geq 
P(\exists n \in \mathbb N \colon \|W_{\tau_n+\cdot} - f\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])} < \epsilon).
$$
But the letter we can estimate by
$$
P(\exists n \in \mathbb N \colon \|W_{\tau_n+\cdot} - f\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])} < \epsilon) \geq 1 - P(\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} \|W_{\tau_n+\cdot} - f\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])} > \epsilon) = 1 - \lim_{N \to \infty} (1-p)^{N} = 1,
$$
since using the fact that $(\tau_n)$ are $P$-almost surely finite we can deduce by the Strong Markov property that $\widetilde{W}_{\cdot} = W_{\tau_{n}+\cdot}-W_{\tau_n}$ is an indepedent Brownian motion of $W_{\tau_{n-1}}$.
Questions: Is this proof correct? Maybe the event is not measurable? Other problems?

What exactly do you mean with the definition of $p$? Do I read it as the probability of randomly selecting an $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $|W(\omega)-f|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ on $[0,1]$? Because in that case, the probability is not one unless $\varepsilon=\infty$.

For me $p$ would depend on $\varepsilon$ in that case in other words if we fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ then $p$ is the probability that sampling from $\omega \in \Omega$ one has $|W(\omega){[0,1]} - f|{\infty} < \epsilon$ or written differently one has $p=P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |W_t - f(t)| < \epsilon)$ for details see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064700/sample-path-of-brownian-motion-within-epsilon-distance-of-continuous-function

Don't you really want the regeneration times to be defined by $\tau_n:=\inf{t>\tau_{n-1}: W_t=0}$? That way the process $(W_{\tau_n+t}){0\le t\le 1}$ is a Brownian motion started at $0$ (strong Markov property) and so  $P\left(|W{\tau_n+\cdot}-f|_{L^\infty[0,1]}<\epsilon\right)$ is the same positive $p$ for all $n$.
Looks good otherwise.
